# Запрет нескольких одновременных вызовов API, реализация блокировки

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, asp

Пишу веб сервис с api-методом, который запускает длительную операцию. Каждый пользователь может запустить только одну такую операцию, если во время выполнения операции приходят новые запросы, их необходимо отбрасывать до завершения предыдущей операции.

Для реализации этого механизма планирую использовать отдельную таблицу в базе данных. Перед началом операции пользователь добавляет в таблицу запись что операция начата, по завершении - удаляет эту запись. При обработке очередного запроса - сначала проверяем выставлена ли блокировка, если её нет - выставляем и запускаем длительную операцию.

```
public class Locker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime LockAcquisitionTime { get; set; }
}
```

Для исключения создания дублированных блокировок - создам уникальный индекс на столбцы {userId, resourceName}:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Locker>()
           .HasIndex(l => new { l.UserId, l.ResourceName })
           .IsUnique(true);
```

На случай, если процесс, получивший блокировку упадет до того как освободит её, для каждой операции задается максимальное время её выполнения, после истечения которого блокировка автоматически снимется.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Получить блокировку для заданного ресурса
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId">Id пользователя, который хочет получить доступ к ресурсу</param>
    /// <param name="resourceName">Id ресурса/операции</param>
    /// <returns>true, если блокировка была получена, false - если ресурс занят</returns>
    public async Task<bool> Acquire(int userId, string resourceName)
    {
        var now = timeService.GetCurrentUtcTime();
        
        var locker = await dbContext.Lockers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.UserId == userId && l.ResourceName == resourceName);
        if (locker == null) // блокировка не была установлена
        {
            locker = new Locker()
            {
                UserId = userId,
                ResourceName = resourceName,
                LockAcquisitionTime = now,
            };
            try
            {
                dbContext.Lockers.Add(locker);
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch(DbUpdateException)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        else if(now - locker.LockAcquisitionTime >= MAX_OPERATION_TIME) // таймаут операции (на случай, если блокировка не была освобождена по какой-то причине)
        {
            try
            {
                dbContext.Lockers.Remove(locker);
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return await Acquire(userId, resourceName); 
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Снять блокировку
    /// </summary>
    public async Task Release(int userId, string resourceName)
    {
        var locker = await dbContext.Lockers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.UserId == userId && l.ResourceName == resourceName);
        if(locker != null)
        {
            dbContext.Lockers.Remove(locker);
            try
            {
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

База данных mssql, но в последствии, возможно, перейду на другую, поэтому не хочу сейчас привязываться к какой-то конкретной.

Насколько этот подход жизнеспособный? Нет ли в нем ошибок? Какие есть альтернативные варианты использования?

**udp**
сохранять блокировки планирую в базе, на случай, если будет несколько экземпляров api-сервиса.  В таком случае кэш должен быть общим. Кэш с блокировками должен быть вне сервиса, т.к. длительная операция - это операция в стороннем сервисе, поэтому если приложение упадет, то блокировки должны где-то сохраниться, что бы при пробуждении api-сервиса не было возможности запустить вторую операцию

Comment: А для этого точно нужна запись в БД? Нельзя ли обойтись записью в кэше в памяти? Тогда и expiration time задаются элементарно, и если сервер упадёт, кэш очистится сам.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в базу планировал класть, на случай, если будет несколько экземпляров api-сервиса.  в таком случае кэш должен быть общим. Длительная операция - это операция в стороннем сервисе, поэтому если приложение упадет, то блокировки должны где-то сохраниться, что бы при пробуждении сервиса не запустить вторую операцию

Comment: База для кэширования не лучшая затея. Для этого лучше использовать `Redist` или нечто подобное, где вы просто заносите ключ с временем "протухания", и при обращении проверяете наличие ключа, все, остальное за вас сделает сам Redist.

Comment: [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Используйте `IDistributedCache`, а реализацию всегда можно поменять.